# How to print xps file in windows8

Tags: printing, windows-8, xps

Is there any blog or document introduces how to print xps file in windows8? I have seen the print sample from official sdk, but not help.

Comment: Do you mean simply printing an XPS file as a user, not writing code to do it?

Comment: Hi @mloar, I want to write code to do that, print xps file in my metro app

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to print directly from a Windows Store app...in my case, I'm creating a pdf document in my app through code.  The best I've been able to do (so far) is to open whatever app/program is associated with the document (XPS Viewer App on WinRT Surface...Adobe Reader on Win 8 Systems if it's installed).  Here's the code I used:

```
StorageFile filetoShare = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync("Document.PDF");
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(filetoShare);
```

In either case it leaves the App and goes directly to the associated program and then requires the user to take action to print.  I'd love to find a way to do this directly from the App.